# PHP on my Windows 2008 server is locking some folders. I can't update wordpress plugins because the folders are in use

Tags: php, wordpress, windows-server-2008

What I mean is, if I try to update a plugin, wordpress deletes the old files, but can't write to the folder. I have to go to the server, open Process Explorer (A program I downloaded) and find what's locking the folder. It's always php.exe, then I close the process for that folder only, and I can then write to it.

How can PHP lock folders so the server can't modify the contents? I need to stop this from happening.

Comment: have you tried to shutdown the site from external users ? maybe they are visiting the site while you're performing an update ?

Comment: I am using the admin screen, the plugin I'm modifying has nothing to do with external users. It's a newsletter plugin which I manage from the backend. If you think that might be the problem, I could try that, but there is no "simple" way to turn off a wordpress site.

Comment: @user1424232: You can stop that by just rebooting your server. When it starts again, keep the webserver service stopped, replace files, and then start the webserver.

Comment: That's a poor way to handle it isn't it? (Genuine question) If I can't add files to a folder, I have to reboot the server every time? This is a site where our customers log in throughout the day to check stock levels, so I can't just take it down on a whim. Is there any good way to stop PHP from locking those folders?